# Can I use return value of INSERT...RETURNING in another INSERT?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, sql-returning

Is something like this possible?

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (val)
VALUES ((INSERT INTO Table1 (name) VALUES ('a_title') RETURNING id));
```

like using the return value as value to insert a row in a second table with a reference to the first table?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can do so starting with Postgres 9.1:

```
with rows as (
INSERT INTO Table1 (name) VALUES ('a_title') RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO Table2 (val)
SELECT id
FROM rows
```

In the meanwhile, if you're only interested in the id, you can do so with a trigger:

```
create function t1_ins_into_t2()
  returns trigger
as $$
begin
  insert into table2 (val) values (new.id);
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger t1_ins_into_t2
  after insert on table1
for each row
execute procedure t1_ins_into_t2();
```

Comment: How to insert values beside the returning id ? for example:
INSERT INTO TABLE2(val1, val2, val3)
(1, 2, SELECT id FROM rows)

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy: replacing `rows` with `(some_query returning ...)` might work nowadays (haven't tried).

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy: To insert values beside the returning id you can do something like this: INSERT INTO TABLE2(val1, val2, val3)  SELECT id, 1, 2 FROM rows

Comment: upvoted! is this atomic meaning if first insert succeeds and second one doesnt what happens then?

Comment: @PirateApp Just tested! v12.4. First INSERT is indeed roll-backed if the second one fails, but the series/autoincrement of the first INSERT is skipped

Answer (score 92):

The best practice for this situation. Use [`RETURNING … INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).

```
INSERT INTO teams VALUES (...) RETURNING id INTO last_id;
```

Note this is for PLPGSQL

Comment: Is this actually a thing? No part of the doc you linked to seems to mention `RETURNING ... INTO`.

Comment: @Alec: I found [this documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328286/4174789).

Comment: @PedroD: It does.

Comment: Very useful. In case it's not clear to other readers, you can also `RETURNING col1, col2 INTO var1, var2`

Comment: @alecbz Wow. Finally. I just spent the past 3 hours looking for this answer, whicch ought to be marked as the correct one. I just want to store it in a variable to be reused. The whole `WITH` clause was far too complicated for what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 24):

```
DO $$
DECLARE tableId integer;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Table1 (name) VALUES ('a_title') RETURNING id INTO tableId;
  INSERT INTO Table2 (val) VALUES (tableId);
END $$;
```

Tested with psql (10.3, server 9.6.8)

Answer (score 19):

In line with the answer given by Denis de Bernardy..

If you want id to be returned afterwards as well and want to insert more things into Table2:

```
with rows as (
INSERT INTO Table1 (name) VALUES ('a_title') RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO Table2 (val, val2, val3)
SELECT id, 'val2value', 'val3value'
FROM rows
RETURNING val
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`lastval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) function:

> Return value most recently obtained with `nextval` for any sequence

So something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name) VALUES ('a_title');
INSERT INTO Table2 (val)  VALUES (lastval());
```

This will work fine as long as no one calls `nextval()` on any other sequence (in the current session) between your INSERTs.

As [Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417194/denis) noted below and I warned about above, using `lastval()` can get you into trouble if another sequence is accessed using `nextval()` between your INSERTs. This could happen if there was an INSERT trigger on `Table1` that manually called `nextval()` on a sequence or, more likely, did an INSERT on a table with a [`SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) primary key. If you want to be really paranoid (a good thing, *they* really are you to get you after all), then you could use [`currval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) but you'd need to know the name of the relevant sequence:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name) VALUES ('a_title');
INSERT INTO Table2 (val)  VALUES (currval('Table1_id_seq'::regclass));
```

The automatically generated sequence is usually named `t_c_seq` where `t` is the table name and `c` is the column name but you can always find out by going into `psql` and saying:

```
=> \d table_name;
```

and then looking at the default value for the column in question, for example:

```
id | integer | not null default nextval('people_id_seq'::regclass)
```

FYI: `lastval()` is, more or less, the PostgreSQL version of MySQL's [`LAST_INSERT_ID`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). I only mention this because a lot of people are more familiar with MySQL than PostgreSQL so linking `lastval()` to something familiar might clarify things.

Comment: Better use currval(), though, in case a trigger on table1 does subsequent inserts.

Comment: @Denis: True, but then you need the name of the sequence. I'll add a little update to that effect just to cover all the bases.

Comment: LASTVAL() and CURRVAL() both work for the current database connection, not for other connections. Other users can update the sequence at the samen time, that won't change your results. Don't worry about others, they will never change your results for LASTVAL and/of CURRVAL. LASTVAL and CURRVAL can't be used at all when using a connectionpool without a TRANSACTION, that's when things go wrong: You don't control the database connection.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, they're all session specific but the problem with `lastval` is that there could be a sequence based INSERT behind your back from an AFTER INSERT trigger on Table1. That would be in the current session and would, presumably, change `lastval()` when you're not expecting it.

Answer (score 2):

> table_ex
>
> id  default nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass),
>
> camp1 varchar
>
> camp2 varchar

```
INSERT INTO table_ex(camp1,camp2) VALUES ('xxx','123') RETURNING id
```