# SELECT INTO with more than one attribution

Tags: sql, postgresql, variable-assignment, plpgsql

This instruction works:

```
SELECT INTO unsolvedNodes array_agg(DISTINCT idDestination)
FROM road 
WHERE idOrigin = ANY(solvedNodes)
AND NOT (idDestination = ANY(solvedNodes));
```

But I would like to use something this way:

```
SELECT INTO unsolvedNodes array_agg(DISTINCT idDestination), lengths array_agg(length)
FROM road
WHERE idOrigin = ANY(solvedNodes)
AND NOT (idDestination = ANY(solvedNodes));
```

How to use only one `SELECT INTO` instruction to set multiple variables?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In **PL/pgSQL** you can `SELECT INTO` *as many variables at once as you like* directly. You just had the syntax backwards:

```
SELECT INTO unsolvedNodes, lengths 
       array_agg(DISTINCT idDestination), array_agg(length)
FROM   road
WHERE  idOrigin = ANY(solvedNodes)
AND    NOT (idDestination = ANY(solvedNodes));
```

You have the keyword `INTO` followed by a list of target variables, and you have a corresponding `SELECT` list. The target of the `INTO` clause can be (quoting [the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)):

> ...a record variable, a row variable, or a comma-separated list of
> simple variables and record/row fields.

Also:

> The `INTO` clause can appear almost anywhere in the SQL command.
> Customarily it is written either just before or just after the list of
> select_expressions in a `SELECT` command, or at the end of the command
> for other command types. It is recommended that you follow this
> convention in case the PL/pgSQL parser becomes stricter in future versions.

This is **not to be confused** with [`SELECT INTO` in the SQL dialect of Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) - which should not be used any more. It goes against standard SQL and will eventually be removed, most likely. The manual actively discourages its continued use:

> It is best to use `CREATE TABLE AS` for this purpose in new code.

Answer (score 36):

Yes,

```
SELECT name,family INTO cName, cFamily FROM "CommonUsersModel";
```

OR

```
SELECT INTO cName, cFamily name,family  FROM "CommonUsersModel"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    DO 
  $$
  DECLARE var_one UUID; 
    var_two UUID;  
    var_three UUID;  
    var_four UUID;  
    var_five UUID;
 BEGIN
     Select INTO var_one,var_two,var_three,var_four,var_five
              h.foocol1,  
              h.foocol2,  
              h.foocol3,  
              h.foocol4,  
              h.foocol5
    from footable h
    where h.fooid = 2;

END;
$$;
```

This is how you can set multiple variables using `SELECT INTO`

Thanks !