# Issue when returning result in PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I come from SQL Server world to PostgreSQL (9.0), and I am having a issue while migrating an stored procedure / function. The function is returning this error message:

```
SQLSTATE: 42601;
SQLERRM: query has no destination for result data
```

I need to return both, the query results and the two out params. The query results are represented as two columns named 'paramName' and 'value' with one row of data per select query.

What I need to do pass the values from columns selected by the query along with the OUT parameters in different resultsets like Transact-SQL does perfectly and avoid getting that error message?

This is the pl/pgsql function:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myplfunction(
            IN i_param1 character varying,
            IN i_param2 character varying,
            IN i_param3 character varying,
            IN i_param4 character varying,
            OUT o_call_status integer,
            OUT o_call_message character varying)
          RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
        $BODY$
        DECLARE 
        val1 varchar;
        val2 varchar;
        val4 varchar;
       BEGIN
        -- A couple of IF THEN ommited here
        IF (v_solution_id IS NULL) THEN
            val1 := (Select column1 FROM tbl2 WHERE column2= i_param1);
            IF(val1 IS NULL) THEN
                o_call_status := 1005;
                o_call_message := column1 is not configured or invalid';
                RETURN;
            END IF;
        END IF;

            SELECT 'mycolumnname1' as paramName,mycolumn1 as value FROM tb1 
            WHERE column1 = val
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'mycolumnname2' as paramName,mycolumn2 as value  FROM tb1 
            WHERE column1 = val
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'mycolumnname3' as paramName,mycolumn3 as value  FROM tb2 
            WHERE column1 = val1 AND
            column4 = val4;      

            o_call_status := 0;
            o_call_message := '';
        RETURN;

            EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                o_call_message := SQLERRM;
                o_call_status := SQLSTATE;
        end;
```

I am getting just the query result or the out params in the resultset. I am not able to figure out how to have both in the same function response.

**UPDATE:** Implemented with cursors as suggested by Erwin:

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myplfunction(
            IN i_param1 character varying,
            IN i_param2 character varying,
            IN i_param3 character varying,
            IN i_param4 character varying,
            OUT o_call_status integer,
            OUT o_call_message character varying)
          RETURNS refcursor AS
        $BODY$
        DECLARE 
        val1 varchar;
        val2 varchar;
        query_cursor refcursor;
       BEGIN
        -- A couple of IF THEN ommited here
        IF (v_solution_id IS NULL) THEN
            val1 := (Select column1 FROM tbl2 WHERE column2= i_param1);
            IF(val1 IS NULL) THEN
                o_call_status := 1005;
                o_call_message := column1 is not configured or invalid';
                RETURN;
            END IF;
        END IF;

            open  query_cursor for SELECT 'mycolumnname1' as paramName,
                                           mycolumn1 as value FROM tb1 
            WHERE column1 = val
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'mycolumnname2' as paramName,mycolumn2 as value  FROM tb1 
            WHERE column1 = val
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'mycolumnname3' as paramName,mycolumn3 as value  FROM tb2 
            WHERE column1 = val1 AND
            column4 = val4;     

            o_call_status := 0;
            o_call_message := '';
            RETURN query_cursor;

            EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                o_call_message := SQLERRM;
                o_call_status := SQLSTATE;
       end;

select * from  myplfunction(param1,param2,param3,param4);
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR: function result type must be record because of OUT parameters
SQL state: 42P13
```

So this means I can not return a cursor when I have OUT params?

Also, does the `return;` in the `IF THEN` clause sentence terminates the function as intended?

Comment: You need to at the minimum provide the entire function.

Comment: Hi @Bob I just ommited a couple of `IF THEN` at the beggining that is all

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of mistakes. This should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myplfunction(i_param1 text, i_param2 text
                                      , i_param3 text, i_param4 text)
  RETURNS TABLE(param_name text, param_value text) AS
$func$
DECLARE 
   val1 text;
   val2 text;
   o_call_status integer;   o_call_message text;   -- without purpose
BEGIN
   IF v_solution_id IS NULL THEN
      val1 := (SELECT column1 FROM tbl2 WHERE column2 = i_param1);
      IF val1 IS NULL THEN
         o_call_status  := 1005;
         o_call_message := 'column1 is not configured or invalid';
         -- I suggest this alternative:
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'column1 is not configured or invalid';
      END IF;
   END IF;

   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT 'mycolumnname1'::text, mycolumn1 FROM tb1 WHERE column1 = val -- val?
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'mycolumnname2', mycolumn2 FROM tb1 WHERE column1 = val       -- val?
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'mycolumnname3', mycolumn2 FROM tb2 WHERE column2 = val2 
                                              AND tb2paramName4 = i_val3;      
   o_call_status := 0;
   o_call_message := '';

   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
      o_call_message := SQLERRM;
      o_call_status  := SQLSTATE;      -- without purpose
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Solution to the **main problem**: Use [**`RETURN QUERY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to actually *return* the result. The SELECT without target caused the error message.
- Multiple sloppy mistakes: missing single quote, supernumerary commas, missing `END IF;`, multiple `WHERE` clauses ...
- You need to cast the string literal to match the declared output type: `'mycolumnname1'::text`
- The form `val1 := column1 FROM tbl2 WHERE ...;` is possible but discouraged. It's better not to mix plpgsql and SQL code this way. Use the alternative I provided (only for a single parameter) or [`SELECT INTO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311634/select-into-with-more-than-one-attribution/16311870#16311870).
- I would advise not to use CaMeL-cased identifiers, even if that's allowed. Unless double-quoted those are converted to lower case.

Comment: The END IF was a mistake in the when submiting the question, not in the acyual function. Then o_call_message and o_call_status  are for internal reasons in the app I can not ommit them.

Comment: @Douglas: You cannot use them as displayed either.

Comment: The o_call_message and o_call_status params are for internal reasons in the app, so I can not ommit them even if I want. Noted not mix plpgsql and SQL, I missed that. Please check the updated plpgsql code and share your thoughts.

Comment: @Douglas: I remember answering *this question* before, suggesting a cursor if you want to return both the table *and* two variables. But I can't find the question any more. (?)

Comment: you are correct, I haved deleted it to avoid ambiguity and rephrase my concern accurately. When using the sugested approach of 'Cursor' and using FETCH ALL, can the result returned be fetched into a SETOF 'RECORD' type?

Comment: @Douglas: You have also deleted my answer by deleting the question and I have put a lot of effort into that. Please undelete.

Comment: Dear @Erwin, apologize for that I have undeleted it. Currently what I am getting is an `SETOF Record` or the `out params` but not both. Is there a way to implement this like in Transact-SQL where I can have multiple resultsets in the response?

Comment: Can a same PLPGSLQ function return OUT params plus a query result, if so how?

Comment: @Douglas: No, `OUT` parameters just define the query result.