# "Syntax error at or near ' , '" while trying to SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5, select-into

The query for selecting multiple values and assigning to multiple variables in a single `SELECT` query leads to an error. My Postgres version is 9.5.
The query is:

```
 SELECT INTO region_id ,doc_type,tax_amt fk_bint_supplier_tax_region_id,chr_supporting_document_type,
dbl_base_currency_client_net-dbl_base_currency_market_fare-dbl_base_currency_cc_charge_collected+
dbl_base_currency_vat_in+dbl_base_currency_cc_charge_collected+(19*(dbl_base_currency_tax))*5/10   
FROM tbl_sales_details   WHERE chr_document_status='N' AND vchr_document_no='INV/47922/01/18'
AND vchr_supporting_document_no='5111143004'
```

The error is:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
> LINE 1:  SELECT INTO region_id ,doc_type,tax_amt fk_bint_supplier_ta...
>                                ^
> ```

********** Error **********

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
> SQL state: 42601
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) in PL/pgSQL has a different meaning from
[`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) in SQL. The latter is generally discouraged. The manual:

> `CREATE TABLE AS` is functionally similar to `SELECT INTO`. `CREATE TABLE AS`
> is the recommended syntax, since this form of `SELECT INTO` is not
> available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the `INTO` clause
> differently. Furthermore, `CREATE TABLE AS` offers a superset of the
> functionality provided by `SELECT INTO`.

The error message indicates you tried to run the statement as plain SQL.

There's nothing wrong with your placement of the `INTO` clause when used in PL/pgSQL like you tagged. You also stated that it's for:

> assigning to multiple variables

That, too, only makes sense inside procedural language code as there are no variable assignments in plain SQL.

Related:

- [SELECT INTO with more than one attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311634/select-into-with-more-than-one-attribution/16311870#16311870)

Answer (score 3):

You put the `into` after the column list:

```
SELECT region_id, doc_type,tax_amt fk_bint_supplier_tax_region_id, chr_supporting_document_type,
       (dbl_base_currency_client_net - dbl_base_currency_market_fare - 
        dbl_base_currency_cc_charge_collected + 
        dbl_base_currency_vat_in + dbl_base_currency_cc_charge_collected + 19 * dbl_base_currency_tax
       ) * 5/10   
INTO . . . 
FROM tbl_sales_details
WHERE chr_document_status = 'N' AND
      vchr_document_no = 'INV/47922/01/18' AND
      vchr_supporting_document_no = '5111143004';
```

I don't know what the variable names are, but the go after the `INTO` and there must be one for each expression in the `SELECT`.

Comment: The placement of `INTO` would be correct - in PL/pgSQL `SELECT INTO`. Seems like the OP and you both are confusing that with SQL `SELECT INTO`. Granted - a bit of a trap.