# What is the proper Syntax of SELECT INTO in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm converting an app from MySQL to Postgres and some triggers need to meticulously converted.

In MySQL the triggers access data from another table to update data in the current table and the syntax is:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name INTO v_instructorfname, v_instructorlname from instructors WHERE objid = NEW.instructor_id;
```

I'm not as proficient with Postgres so I'd like to determine the proper syntax to execute this same line of code in Postgres. I've been searching Google for about 30 minutes without finding a relevant answer.

Would appreciate some tips on the syntax that works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT INTO with more than one attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311634/select-into-with-more-than-one-attribution)

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
SELECT first_name AS v_instructorfname, last_name AS v_instructorlname FROM instructors ...
```