# Is there any way to store a value from a query then use in the next query below it?

Tags: database, postgresql

i have a Postgres SQL database that has quizes, questions, answers and marks on there (multiple tables) im trying to write a query to work out the maxscore for one quiz and then update the quiz table using the query thats just calculated the max score

Heres my querys

```
SELECT SUM( maxscore)
FROM (
  SELECT max(answer.answermark) AS maxscore
  FROM answer, questions
  WHERE questions.quizid = 1 AND answer.questionid = questions.questionid
  GROUP BY answer.questionid
) scr;

UPDATE quiz
SET maxscore = '50'
WHERE quizid = 1
```

where "`SET maxscore = '50'`" i need to instead of typing 50 i need to use the calculation from the query above, is there any way ??

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-the-query-result-in-variable-using-postgresql-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

try with cte:

```
with v as (
SELECT SUM( maxscore)
FROM (
  SELECT max(answer.answermark) AS maxscore
  FROM answer, questions
  WHERE questions.quizid = 1 AND answer.questionid = questions.questionid
  GROUP BY answer.questionid
)
UPDATE quiz
SET maxscore = v.sum
from v
WHERE quizid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not need to keep state. Do it in `from` clause:

```
update quiz
set maxscore = scr.maxscore
from (
    select sum(maxscore) as maxscore
    from (
        select max(a.answermark) as maxscore
        from
            answer a
            inner join
            questions q using (questionid)
        where q.quizid = 1
        group by questionid
    ) s
) scr
where quizid = 1
```

If you want to do it for all `quizid`:

```
update quiz
set maxscore = scr.maxscore
from (
    select quizid, sum(maxscore) as maxscore
    from (
        select quizid, max(a.answermark) as maxscore
        from
            answer a
            inner join
            questions q using (questionid)
        group by quizid, questionid
    ) s
    group by quizid
) scr
where quiz.quizid = scr.quizid
```