# Redshift UNLOAD concatenate file name

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a UNLOAD query in Redshift where I need the file name to be generated dynamically like 'Filename.year.quarter' and I am passing a query to derive year and quarter like below:

```
UNLOAD('Query1') 
TO  '::P1::/test/test_folder'
     || (select ent_qtr 
         from db.w_day_d 
         where calendar_date=to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00')) 
     || (select ent_year 
         from db.w_day_d 
         where calendar_date=to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00')) 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=::P2::;aws_secret_access_key=::P3::' ADDQUOTES
DELIMITER as ',' ALLOWOVERWRITE NULL as ''  HEADER PARALLEL OFF;
```

But this query is not allowing me to use || operator too. Can anyone please suggest a better way in deriving a filename like 'Filename.year.quarter' ?

Thanks

Comment: why dont use `SELECT .... INTO @variable` first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-query-result-in-a-variable-using-in-pl-pgsql

Comment: BTW You can find the year and quarter in a single query.   `select ent_year || '.' || ent_qtr INTO  file_name` . And year should be first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But I wanted something the filename like  UNLOAD('Query1') 
TO  '::P1::/test/test_folder_'|| ent_year || '.Q' || ent_qtr from db.w_day_d where calendar_date=to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00') where the filename generated would be test_folder_2019.Q4

Comment: That is what I said. Use `SELECT .... INTO @variable` and then `UNLOAD('Query1') TO  || @variable`