# Select 1 into variable postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have this select statement inside a trigger procedure:

```sql
  SELECT 1 FROM some_table WHERE "user_id" = new."user_id"
  AND created >= now()::date;
```

How can i store result in a variable and reuse it in IF statement like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (var_name) THEN ...;
```

procedure (for now i have select right in IF statement, but i want it separately)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_row() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    //need to check if row was created around today
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_table WHERE "user_id" = new."user_id"
  AND created >= now()::date) THEN
      INSERT INTO another_table VALUES(1, 2, 3);
    END IF;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us your complete PL/pgSQL function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store query result in a variable using in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-query-result-in-a-variable-using-in-pl-pgsql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the result of a query into a variable, you need to declare a variable. Then you can use `select .. into ..` to [store the result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW). But I would use a `boolean` and an exists condition for this purpose.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_row() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $$
declare
  l_row_exists boolean;
BEGIN
  select exists (SELECT *
                 FROM some_table 
                 WHERE user_id = new.user_id
                  AND created >= current_date)
    into l_row_exists;

  IF NOT l_row_exists THEN
    INSERT INTO another_table (col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES(1, 2, 3);
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, you don't really need an IF statement to begin with. You can simplify this to a single INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO another_table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 1,2,3 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM some_table 
                  WHERE user_id = new.user_id
                    AND created >= current_date);
```