# How to convert integer[] to jsonb in a PL/pgSQL code block

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

How to convert `integer[]` to `jsonb`?

```
declare ids int[];
declare jsonids jsonb;

jsonids := array(select id from student); -- what should I do here?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

```
jsonids := to_jsonb(ARRAY(SELECT id FROM student));
```

Or:

```
SELECT INTO jsonids to_jsonb(ARRAY(SELECT id FROM student));
```

`array_to_json()` is only still useful to get line feeds in `json` (not `jsonb`!). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE)

> Converts an SQL array to a JSON array. The behavior is the same as
> `to_json` except that line feeds will be added between top-level array
> elements if the optional boolean parameter is true.

See:

- [Store query result in a variable using in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-query-result-in-a-variable-using-in-pl-pgsql/12328820#12328820)

To convert back:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(id)) into jsonids from student
```