# Update columns for the first user inserted

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a trigger and a function to update some columns (roles and is_verified) for the first user created. Here is my function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.first_user()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE 
    begin
        if(select count(*) from public.user = 1) then
        update new set new.is_verified = true and new.roles = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"]
        end if;
    return new;
    end;
$function$
;
```

and my trigger :

```
create trigger first_user
before insert
    on
    public.user for each row execute function first_user()
```

I'm working on Dbeaver and Dbeaver won't persist my function because of a syntax error near the "=". Any idea ?

Comment: This needs a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES). `if ((select count(*) from public.user) = 1) then`. And `new.is_verified := true; new.roles := array['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']` too. No`update`  is needed, just assignments.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Store query result in a variable using in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-query-result-in-a-variable-using-in-pl-pgsql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few things are wrong in your trigger function. Here it is revised w/o changing your business logic.
However this will affect the second user, not the first. Probably you shall compare the count to 0. Then the condition shall be `if not exists (select from public.user) then`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.first_user()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$function$
begin
   if ((select count(*) from public.user) = 1) then
   -- probably if not exists (select from public.user) then
        new.is_verified := true;
        new.roles := array['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'];
   end if;
   return new;
end;
$function$;
```

Comment: I try with if not exists, Dbeaver is ok to persist but in fact when I insert the first user nothing change

Comment: Was the table empty? Did you run `select * from public.user` to see what is there in it?

Comment: My bad it's ok. I change new.roles because it's a json not an array.