# How to declare and use a variable in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, syntax-error

I'm new to PostgreSQL, so maybe my question is unconvinced. But what I want is to put the result of one query into a variable and then used it again in another query. I run my query inside pgAdmin4, Below is my query:

Also I tried those [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-psql), [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-query-result-in-a-variable-using-in-pl-pgsql) without achieving my goal.

```
WITH vars AS (
    (select count(*) from employee) AS vars_id
)
select 
    *
from 
    employee
where
    id=vars.vars_id;
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2:  (select count(*) from employee) AS vars_id
                                         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 49
```

Comment: `where
    id=vars.vars_id;` => `where
    id = (SELECT vars.vars_id FROM vars);`

Comment: `vars` is a table, not a single record. There are no such variables in plain SQL.

Comment: I updated my question, it gives me this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a CTE is a table expression. You can't just refer to it as a scalar, you need to query from it:

```sql
WITH vars AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS vars_id FROM employee
)
SELECT *
FROM   employee e
JOIN   vars ON e.id = vars.vars_id
```

Comment: I implemented your solution, it gives me the same error as mine.

Comment: @NZJL ooh, the `as` clause is misplaced. Didn't even notice that, mea culpe. See my edited answer.