# why does it states that my sql statement needs no parameters

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, plpgsql, pgpool

```
`do $$declare temp_id integer;
begin;
insert INTO public.logindetails(email, pass, dept, designation, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);
select login_id into temp_id from public.logindetails where email = $1;
INSERT INTO public.studentdetails(login_id, curr_year, enroll_no,full_name) VALUES (temp_id, $6, $7, $8);
end $$;`
```

This is my sql statement that I am trying to execute in my express application.
[image]
This is my server-side post endpoint.
Below is my client-side js:
[image]

and the error I am getting is :
[image]
I have tried doing it in gui of postgreSQL and it works fine:
[image]
Can any one figure out a work through or the part where I am going wrong and a solution to it.

Just see if this helps:
[image]
Assistance appreciated greatly.

Comment: What's the implementation of `hash`? That password hashing looks suspicious. Anyway, it's the `DO`. Can't parameterize those. Use `INSERT … RETURNING` to avoid the `SELECT`.

Comment: @Ry- why does this hashing looks suspicious?
2) Thank you I found a solution :     
     `WITH getID AS (
        INSERT INTO public.logindetails(email, pass, dept, designation, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING login_id
        )
    INSERT INTO public.studentdetails(login_id, curr_year, enroll_no, full_name) 
    SELECT login_id, $6, $7, $8 FROM getID;`       if you have even better solution then please provide me the better solution.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Re: the hashing: the salt is way too big. Did you mean 128 bits instead of 128 bytes?

Comment: Yes I did mean 128 bits is it considering as bytes? because the person who told me to use pbkdfsync told me that it takes bits.

Comment: Yep, it takes a byte count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem as the comment of @Ry- gave me a direction and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561437/8217589) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465491/8217589) helped me further with the solution.
 **SOLUTION :** 
 If you have to do statements like the one I have been attempting then the workaround is:

> WITH getID AS (INSERT INTO public.logindetails(email, pass, dept, designation, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING login_id)
> INSERT INTO public.studentdetails(login_id, curr_year, enroll_no, full_name) 
>    SELECT login_id, $6, $7, $8 FROM getID;

and then pass the parameters as required.