# How to return id from table_1 and and insert into table_2

Tags: sql, insert, request, psql

I try send INSERT one request in postgresql DB. I want insert into table users login and password, then take away from users id, and insert in the ud_user into tables personal_data it id, and other params(name, gender etc).

```
INSERT INTO personal_data (id_user, name, gender, city)
VALUES ((INSERT INTO users (login, password) 
VALUES('123', '123')
RETURNING id), 'Max', 'Male', 'Moscow');
```

syntax error at or newar "INTO"
LINE 2: VALUES ((INSERT INTO users...

Comment: Hello Pavel. Welcome to SO, you are using incorrect syntax, here is the answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561437/2460416

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can update both tables in the same statement using CTEs:

```
WITH u as (
      INSERT INTO users (login, password) 
          VALUES('123', '123')
          RETURNING id
     )
INSERT INTO personal_data (id_user, name, gender, city)
    SELECT id, 'Max', 'Male', 'Moscow'
    FROM u;
```

Comment: Thank's, this's whant i need.