# How to create a PostgreSQL Table id Field and Define a Custom Sequence for It?

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

My table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts IF NOT EXISTS (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
   name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

At some circumstances, I want to fetch next val of id before inserting data into a table at PostgreSQL. So, I created a sequence for that:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS accounts_sequence
```

I can fetch the next val from sequence and then use it at insert. However, it needs to be auto incremented by same sequence if I insert a row without providing the id.

How can I create a PostgreSQL table id field and define a custom sequence for it?

Comment: When you use SERIAL, a sequence is automatically created. Just use nextval() on that sequence, which would be accounts_id_seq by default given your table & column names. If you want the id column to use your sequence instead, use ALTER TABLE to change the default value for the id column. (But I would just use the auto-created sequence.)

Comment: I want to implement a logic at my backend code. How can I know the generated sequence for that table or can I alter it to use my sequence?

Comment: Both are possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698777/16361) for using the existing sequence, or the ALTER TABLE docs for how to change a column default value.

Comment: Why? If you are pulling from the same sequence in each case, why not just let the `id` come from the column `DEFAULT next_val(<some_seq>)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `serial` column will automatically create a sequence in the background.

If you want to manually call `nextval()` you can use `pg_get_serial_sequence()` to obtain the sequence name:

```
 select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('accounts', 'id'));
```

Note that the use of `serial` is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) in modern Postgres versions in favor of `identity` columns.

Comment: It's vexing that serial is discouraged in favor of identity, but serial has much better documentation. The [serial docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) point you to look at [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtable.html) for info on identity columns, but there is very little information to be found.

Comment: Yes there is. In the CREATE TABLE section it is in the links [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) and [CREATE SEQUENCE)(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html). Further information here [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)  An `identity` column is  a SQL compliant wrapper around a `sequence` that more tightly binds the `sequence` to the <table>.<column>.

Comment: Does `pg_get_serial_sequence` works for `identity` too?

Comment: @kamaci: yes, this works for identity columns as well

Answer (score 0):

So, as it's already been stated, a serial column will create a sequence for you. Further, that sequence will be automatically incremented if you leave out the `id` field in an INSERT query.

It sounds like for your back end code, you sometimes need to get the `id` value when doing an INSERT. There are two ways I know of to do this:

1. Use `SELECT nextval(<mysequence>)`. Then inject that number into your INSERT query.
2. Use a [RETURNING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html) clause in your INSERT query. In that case the data is saved in the database and your fields are returned. I use this strategy a lot.

Using the second method, your query might look like this

```
INSERT INTO accounts (name) 
VALUES ('Joe Cool') 
RETURNING id;
```

Depending on how complicated your backend is, you might also be able to interact with two tables using a CTE. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561437/9705687) has a good example of using a WITH statement to use the id from one INSERT into another INSERT all in the same query.