# Get Primary Key after using CFINSERT - ColdFusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, primary-key, cfquery

When I use `CFINSERT` the form data is inserted into my database because the field names match the column names.

**MY QUESTION:** How can I get the primary key of the row I just added using the CFINSERT?

I know I cant use "Result='variable'" similar to a standard `cfquery` so what is the best way to get the primary key?

If I run the following query directly after my cfinsert it should return the pervious PK:

```
<cfquery name="getID" datasource="#mydsn#" result="#result#">
select Max(id) as NewID from myTablename;
</cfquery>
```

Is this the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: What database system are you using? Also, are you determined to use `<cfinsert>`? Maybe `<cfquery>` with one INSERT statement to insert the data and one SELECT statment to grab the new ID would be a useful alternative.

Comment: I just found this: <cfquery name="getID" datasource="#mydsn#" result="#result#">
select Max(id) as NewID from myTablename;
</cfquery>

Comment: Which I think will work if I run it after my cfinsert. I am using a MSSQL server to answer your question.

Comment: That's not good because it is a race condition - when two forms are submitted at the same time, then both times the `SELECT MAX(id)` will return the same value.

Comment: I thought that might be an issue. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: That depends on your database system. SQL Server has [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to solve this particular problem. Other DB systems use different functions. So, it depends.

Comment: I am not sure if that can be combined with cfinsert since I am not actually writing the query to use Scope_Identity.

Comment: That's why I asked whether you are determined to use `<cfinsert>` or not. You see, if you only had answered the two questions in my first comment...

Comment: Sorry I had answered it but it looks like it got cut off between my second and third comment when I clicked return by accident. YES I want to use cfinsert because I have over 120+ inputs and this will save me time.

Comment: I still don't know your database system so you kind of not really answered the other question. Really, it's 10 comments later now.

Comment: Which I think will work if I run it after my cfinsert. I am using a MSSQL server to answer your question. –  Denoteone 15 mins ago  Was that not enough information?

Comment: Hm, okay, that slipped through. Sorry. So, instead of `MAX(id)` use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewId` in a cfquery.

Comment: I will do that. If you put it in an answer I can mark it as closed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that avoids the race condition, because if you do a cfinsert and a separate cfquery that's two batches (Docs: *"two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch"*). Does `SCOPE_IDENTITY` even return a value when used like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Inserting a row and returning primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479315/sql-inserting-a-row-and-returning-primary-key)

Comment: @da_didi Not really a duplicate because the circumstances are special to how this can be used in ColdFusion.

Comment: Don't use `cfinsert`.....ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on SQL Server you can use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function to safely grab the last inserted identity value in the current scope.

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) says

> **SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)**
>
> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

When used in two separate ColdFusion tags (`<cfinsert>` followed by `<cfquery>`) then that's two batches and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will not work anymore. Therefore the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` statement will have to be part of the same batch. Unfortunately this cannot be achieved with `<cfinsert>`.

You said you had many fields in your form post, so I would do something like this:

```
<cfset fieldNames = "all,relevant,field,names,from,http,post">
<cfset fieldTypes = "INTEGER,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,DATETIME,INTEGER,VARCHAR,VARCHAR">
<cfset fieldNullable = "false,true,true,true,false,true,false">
<cfset fieldCount = ListLen(fieldNames)>

<!--- default "" for any fields missing from the HTTP POST --->
<cfloop from="1" to="#fieldCount#" index="i">
  <cfparam name="FORM.#ListGetAt(fieldNames, i)#" default="">
</cfloop>

<cfquery name="insert" datasource="#yourdatasource#">
  INSERT YourTable (#fieldNames#)
  VALUES (
    <cfloop from="1" to="#fieldCount#" index="i">
      <cfif i gt 1>,</cfif>
      <cfset val = FORM[ListGetAt(fieldNames, i)]>
      <cfset type = "CF_SQL_#ListGetAt(fieldTypes, i)#">
      <cfset null = ListGetAt(fieldNullable, i) eq "true" and val eq "">
      <cfqueryparam value="#val#" cfsqltype="#type#" null="#null#">
    </cfloop>
  )

  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewId
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#insert#">
```

Comment: If you are going to use cfquery, the result attribute is simpler.  The use of the loop is clever though.

Comment: Ah, you're right, `insert.IDENTITYCOL` is actually simpler.

Comment: *then that's two batches* True, though FWIW wrapping multiple sql statements in a cftransaction should ensure they keep the same connection. Then you can obtain the scope_identity() value safely. That said agreed using standard `INSERT` + `query.GENERATEDKEY` (db agnostic) is preferred.

Comment: @Leigh I thought about recommending `<cftransaction>` but I am not sure if that is guaranteed to work. In my experience `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns nothing when there was no insert in the current batch.

Comment: @Tomalak - My understanding is `scope_identity` applies to the current session. Wrapping multiple statements in a cftransaction ensures the same session and that guarantees it will work. So the result should be the same as if you executed those two statements in a single SSMS query window, with no `go` in between.

Comment: Lacking an SQL Server for testing I did not want to make uncertain recommendations. If you can verify that this works, go ahead and post it as an alternative answer.

Comment: Edit: @Tomalak - Understood. My comments were more informational about cftransaction and sessions for others reading the thread in the future :) I can verify it works as expected, but I do not think it is worth a separate answer. Compared to the simplicity of using `query.GENERATEDKEY` or a single query with `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewId` using cftransaction with multiple cfquery's would be an unnecessary complication in this case. Plus I do not want to encourage the use of the legacy cfinsert tag ;-) A standard INSERT is the way to go.

Comment: I don't think using `<cftransaction>` is necessary to ensure the same DB session. I suppose it would enable one to roll back the transaction in the (very unlikely) event that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @DavidFaber - Yes, logically it seems like a single request would maintain the same db connection, but... I have never seen it documented that it is "guaranteed".  So it may work without it, but AFAIK the only way to *guarantee* you maintain the same connection is with cftransaction.

Comment: Also, the SQL Server documentation clearly states that it has to be *the same batch*, the same connection is not enough.

Comment: True. Though I think same connection should suffice here.  My understanding is a "batch" consists of one or more statements separated by the TSQL keyword `GO`. Since `GO` is not supported outside of MS clients, I am thinking same connection and batch should be the equivalent in this scenario.

Comment: @Leigh *"A batch is a group of one or more Transact-SQL statements sent at the same time from an application to SQL Server for execution."* ([ref](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) - `GO` separates multiple statements that are sent at the same time into batches. It does not make a batch out of multiple statements sent at different times. Trusting that multiple CF statements will execute in the same batch is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to deal with this is to get the primary key from the `generatedKey` from the query's *result* struct.

```
<cfquery name="myQuery" result="queryResult" datasource="#myDSN#">
    INSERT INTO some_table
    (column_one) 
    VALUES 
    (<cfqueryparam value="#stringForColOne#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">)
</cfquery>
<cfoutput>
    Generated Key from SQL Insert = #queryResult.generatedKey#
</cfoutput>
```

See https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfquery#cfquery-Usage