# Execute a raw query to create object in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table which not defined as a Model in Django server. So I need to use raw query to create object in Database

**My database**:

Table name: `msg_rooms`

[image]

I want to create object `{ with_user: 5, room_name: 'abc', user_id: 2 }` by using raw query in Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw query is only for model related queries. However you can use something like

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    connection.execute(
        "INSERT INTO msg_rooms(with_user, room_name, user_id) "
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", [5, 'abc', 2])
```

You can read more details on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: But how can i get the new id of created object?

Comment: That would depend on your database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479315/sql-inserting-a-row-and-returning-primary-key