# How to get last value from database (postgre) and show it in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Can you please tell me how to get in Qt the last value of column, from database.

I know I can get the last value using while loop, but that is too much work for the program.

Comment: Do you mean the row id (or primary index) of the last insert operation, or the highest id contained in the table ?

Comment: @alexisdm i mean the last insert operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`QSqlQuery::lastInsertId`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId), just after the insert query (For Postgresql, the query must still be active and the table must contain OIDs).

If it doesn't work and the returned `QVariant` is invalid, you can try the other Postgresql methods:

 [postgreSQL function for last inserted ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id)

Comment: I found this way to get the last entry from postgreSQL and Qt

Answer (score 1):

In my case, nothing work what i found in google and here. Finally i found solution. Maybe it's not optimized and pretty but work fine

```
int SomeClass::get_last_id(QString sequence){
  QSqlQuery query(QString("select currval('%1')").arg(sequence), this->dbh);
  query.next();
  return query.value(0).toInt();
}
```

Usage with QSqlTableModel:

```
model->setTable(TABLE_NAME);
model->insertRows(0, 1);
model->setData(model->index(0, parent_domain), _domain);
model->setData(model->index(0, parent_token), _token.mid(0,19).toUpper());
model->setData(model->index(0, parent_name), _name);
model->submitAll();
int id = get_last_id(TABLE_SEQUENCE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QSqlQuery sqlQuery;
sqlQuery.prepare("SELECT \"Ime\", \"Prezime\", \"ID\" FROM tabela;");
sqlQuery.exec();
if (sqlQuery.isActive()){
    if (sqlQuery.isSelect()){
        if (sqlQuery.last()){
            QString string=sqlQuery.value(2).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Solution

Comment: That's not a very good solution because the database might have to generate all the rows even if you are only use one of them. If you only want the last row, use `SELECT Ime, Prezime, id from tabela order by id desc limit 1`.