# How to get autoincrement ID just inserted by ScalaQuery

Tags: scala, primary-key, scalaquery

I am using ScalaQuery to access PostgreSql. `Data` is a table that has an autoincremental primarykey named `id`, defined as `def id = column[Long] ("id", O NotNull, O PrimaryKey, O AutoInc, O DBType "serial")`. I use `Data.insert(name, filename)` to create a new `Data` record. Is there a way to get the `id` of the record that just created? The `insert` method only return an Int value returned by `executeUpdate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScalaQuery does not support sequence ID out-of-the-box, you need to first define a helper method:

```
val seqID = SimpleFunction.nullary[Int]("LASTVAL")
```

then, with above helper in scope, perform your insert:

```
db withSession {
  val q  = Foo.insert(someInstance)
  val id = Query(seqID) // call sequence helper
}
```

as to the comment re: thread safety, please refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944481/185840

and:
https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/issues/10#issuecomment-698418

Comment: Thanks. At the first glance this solution seems thread-unsafe. Is this a problem?

Comment: it is thread safe, the query occurs within session context and LASTVAL guarantees the last inserted ID for the current session