# PHP, Postgres help using RETURNING

Tags: php, postgresql, sql-returning

I think I understand how PostgreSQL and RETURNING works - I've found many, many resources. If I'm catching on, it would look something like

```
"INSERT INTO table (column2, column3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2') RETURNING id;"
```

However, I can't find anything that helps me access this via PHP. When I thought I figured it out, I tried

```
$new_id = pg_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO table (column2, column3) ".
"VALUES ('value1', 'value2') RETURNING id;");
return $new_id;
```

But it returns NULL. I also tried executing and declaring the variable separately with one query. After looking for hours for the solution, I've settled on a max(id) SELECT statement/function, but it's still bothering me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm using Postgres 8.4 and PHP 5.3.

Comment: Are you looking for the last inserted ID? If so, maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id

Comment: I understand how to return the last inserted ID - several different ways, in fact. I want to know how to use the returned ID in a PHP variable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`$new_id` does not contain the id but it is a resource descriptor. You need to fetch the data from it as the query would be a SELECT, with `pg_fetch_array($new_id)` by example.

The `RETURNING` clause of PostgreSQL projects any fields of the inserted or modified rows ie `INSERT|UPDATE … RETURNING id, field1, field2`.

Comment: So, `$resource = pg_query(...); $new_id = pg_fetch_array($resource);` ?

Comment: Actually, as the function returns an array and you need the first (and only) value of it: `list($new_id) = pg_fetch_row($resource);`

Comment: In conclusion, `$query = pg_query("INSERT ... RETURNING id"); $row = pg_fetch_row($query); $new_id = $row['0'];`  !!! Thanks!