# How to select primary key cusomter id using postgres and php

Tags: php, postgresql, select, associative-array

I am trying to grab the newest customer_id created after inserting into postgres it does not seem to be working

```
$result = pg_query_params($dbconn, 'SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE
first_name=$1 AND last_name=$2 ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1',
array($first_name, $last_name));

$resultRow = pg_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $resultRow['customer_id'];
```

what do i need to do to get the customer_id to display

Comment: If you change the order by to last_name, do you get an reply?

Comment: i figured it out i was making a query after pg_close() i should have put the query before the close thanks!!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070752/php-postgres-help-using-returning/13070936