# How can I get the value of an automatically generated postgres id using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

## Question:

Is there a way to get the value of `client.client_id` into a PHP variable to then use it as the value of `phone.client_id`?

## Context:

I have a PostgreSQL database to which I communicate using PHP.

I have two separate tables in the database:

```
client (client_id[PK], client_name)
```

and

```
phone (phone_id[PK], client_id[FK], phone_number)
```

Both `client_id` and `phone_id` are create as `bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807` .

Since the ids are `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` I don't need to to specify them when inserting data into the tables in PHP:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO public.client (client_name) VALUES('" . $clientName . "')";
```

Now to finally get to my question:

Whenever I insert a `client` I also want to insert a `phone`, the `phone` table needs to hold a reference to the `client` to which it belongs, and it does so by having a `client_id` foreign key.

If I was just creating the id in PHP I could use that value in both `INSERT` statements and end up with the correct behaviour.

Is there a way to get the value of `client.client_id` into a PHP variable to then use it as the value of `phone.client_id`?

Comment: See this discussion that your issue will be solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485778/php-postgres-get-last-insert-id

Comment: Thanks both @ErmeSchultz and @MagnusEriksson, that question seems to be exactly what I want to achieve!

However, I didn't quite understand where to put `RETURNING client_id` and how to access the value after.
Will my `client_id` be stored in the `$query` variable?

Comment: another solution might be to generate a UUID in your php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ErmeSchultz and @MagnusEriksson I was able to find a solution in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070752/php-postgres-help-using-returning#comment17783771_13070936).

My modified code is now:

```
// crafting the query so that the variable $query contains the value of the automatically generated client_id
$query = "INSERT INTO public.client (client_name) VALUES('" . $clientName . "') RETURNING client_id";

// getting an array of the elments contained inside $query
$row = pg_fetch_row($query);

// putting the first element inside $row into $client_id
$client_id = $row[0];
```

The variable `$client_id` now contains the value of `client.client_id`!

Comment: improvement on this is using `$row = pg_fetch_assoc($query);` so that then values can be extracted by doing `$client_id = $row['client_id'];`