# getting last inserted row id with PDO (not suitable result)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

I have a problem with `PDO::lastInsertId()` method which doesn't return the id (primary key) of last inserted row, instead it returns another field which is a foreign key field.

***PHP code:***

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(...);
$stmt->bindParam(...);
$stmt->execute();
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
// or
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId('services_id_seq'); // I think 'services_id_seq' is not necessary in MySQL
// both of them don't return the primary key of last inserted row

echo 'last inserted id: ' . $id;
```

***MySQL Table structure:***

```
...
id          int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment
customer_id int unsigned not null
user_id     int unsigned not null
....
```

***inserted row in MySQL:***

```
id    customer_id    user_id    ...
1     19             31         ...
```

***PHP output:***

```
last inserted id: 19
```

It should return `1` not `19`. I don't know is anything wrong with my code or not.. or maybe this is the normal behavior :?

**Return Value (PHP documentation):**

- If a sequence name was not specified for the name parameter,
  `PDO::lastInsertId()` returns a string representing the row `ID` of
  the last row that was inserted into the database.
- If a sequence name was specified for the name parameter, `PDO::lastInsertId()` returns a string representing the last value retrieved from the specified sequence object.
- If the `PDO` driver does not support this capability, `PDO::lastInsertId()` triggers an `IM001 SQLSTATE`.

Comment: To get the serial is not that easy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id#answer-2944335

Comment: @GreenRover thanks, also it is postgresql :( I am using MySQL and I want to know is `PDO::lastInsertId()` the right way or not? or I did a mistake

Comment: my fould i only red the sequenze and not thetag. For MySQL it looks right `$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();`. But check you insert perhaps it is invalid and you get the result of last insert.

Answer (score 1):

Run `"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"` query.
If returned ID is still 19, not 2 (or whatever primary key should be after all tries), there is a problem with MySQL, irrelevant to PDO. You have to investigate it as a separate case (and, probably, separate question), supplying full SQL proof-code, able to run in console, involving creating a table, running insert and selecting LAST_INSERT_ID()

If this function returns the right value but PDO still wrong one - you have to probably bugreport it on bugs.php.net, again with full reproduceable code and all software names with exact version numbers provided.

Only one thing to make it clear: are you certainly sure that `$sql` variable in your question contains proper INSERT statement, not something like INSERT ON DUPLICATE or such?
Or are there any triggers set on this INSERT?

Comment: it is: `$sql = 'INSERT INTO "services" ("customer_id", "user_id", ...) VALUES (:customer_id, :user_id, ...)';` other fields are just varchars and datetime type columns. and also there is no trigger set. I am checking your solution

Answer (score -1):

I looked at PDO::lastInsertId() recently but found the description in the manual insufficiently convincing (or indeed comprehensible) and so opted for using something like this instead:

```
...
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
...
```

which seems to work for me.

I'm no PDO or MySQL expert, so this may not be quite right, but I also thought that the above approach would circumvent the possible problem of another row being inserted in the database (by a different user/thread) in between this thread's execute() and lastInsertID() calls.

If you're keen to keep lastInsertID() have you investigated whether, in your setup, the ID returned has to be an auto-increment field? The manual sort of hints that this should be so but is hopeless vague (IMHO).

Hope that's of some help.

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: @lan thanx. yes it is `auto_increment` and also I edited my question and added mysql table structure