# How to get an INSERT's returned value in a SQL function and use it in that same function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

here's an example to complete the title,
this is the inner of my function (i am using postgresql but i guess this is pure SQL language)

```
$$
  INSERT INTO foo VALUES (DEFAULT, $1) RETURNING id;
  INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar VALUES (1, <?>);
$$ language SQL;
```

two things to notice here, I RETURNING the id of the first insert, how to catch it as to use the returned id as the second argument of the second insert marked as **< ? >**  ?

Comment: Gordon's answer is probably what you need, but I suggest you also [Read this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first column is a serial/primary key, I would use CURRVAL function:

```
$$
  INSERT INTO foo VALUES (DEFAULT, $1);
  INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar VALUES (1, CURRVAL('foo_id_seq'));
$$ language SQL;
```

Comment: neat. i may ask a novice question here but are the INSERT statements synchronous ? what if the first insert has a big load of data to insert, is the CURRVAL going to be updated properly as the process switch on the second INSERT ?

Comment: It is absolutely safe - CURRVAL returns last returned value from any sequence for current session.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a CTE to capture the rows inserted from the first insert:

```
with firstinsert as (
      INSERT INTO foo VALUES (DEFAULT, $1) RETURNING id
     )
INSERT INTO link_foo_to_bar 
    select 1, id
    from firstinsert;
```

Comment: I valid the other answer as it is more neat and logic as the id i'm using is a sequence. but thanks for your answer I didn't know this way of writing constants.

Comment: This example works for any kind of returning value, not just a sequence value.

Comment: @FrankHeikens . . . In addition, it doesn't suffer from race conditions, that can invalidate the other answer.