# saving multiple checkedlistbox values in one single row database using c#

Tags: c#, postgresql

Is it possible to store multiple values in one cell in database?
Based on the picture below on column `famcon`, only one value from a checkedlistbox can be inserted even if the user chose multiple values.

this is my query for this table:

```
foreach (DataRowView item in this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into name (eid, name, famcon) SELECT @eid, @name, @famcon", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
                string[] value = item.Row[0].ToString().Split(',');
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@famcon", value);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: You have 2 solutions : **1)** store all CheckedListBox Checked values as a string (or an integer if the items count is under 32). **2)** create a secondary table to store one value per record with a foreign key refereing to the table pimary key (eid).

Comment: @Graffito should i use the INSERT..SELECT on the query?

Comment: The SQL statement to get the AutoIncrement value allocated by the database server varies. What DB are you using ?

Comment: im using postgresql database

Comment: i tried your second solution, however i got stuck because the 'eid' value wont appear on the table. I tried the INSERT..SELECT query

Comment: With Postgresql, refer to [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id) to get the eid following the INSERT.

Comment: Also replace ExecuteNonQuery() by ExecuteScalar() and cast result to int.

Answer (score 0):

you are not adding the elements of `string[] value` to your field. try:

```
string[] value = item.Row[0].ToString().Split(',');
string insert="";
foreach (string s in value)
{
  insert=" "+s;
}    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@famcon", insert);
```

Comment: an error appears: duplicate key violates unique constraint "pk_eid". i forgot to mention that 'eid' is a primary key. sorry about that.

Comment: If your primary key is autoIncrement, don't include it in the INSERT command, but get it through a SQL statement depending on the DataBase (Oracle, MsAccess, MySQL, SQL Server, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [bitset](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/datatype-bit.html) type, which sets positional flags in a string.

Each bit would represent an individual value, but you would have to maintain the link between bits and values - ie which bit is which.

Alternatively a space or comma separated string works. Each string is a human-readable code that represents a value. You would have to parse the string but its easier to read than bit values.