# How to reference the auto incremented id when performing a second insert in Liquibase?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, liquibase

I am currently playing around with Liquibase and have created a table for users and a table for roles. Each user has a unique id which is auto generated (by a auto increment sequence) when a user is inserted. The roles in the role table are then referencing this id.

Now I try to insert a default user using the Liquibase. First I insert the user and then I want to insert a role which is referring to this newly created user.

The problem is that I can't find a way in Liquibase to retrieve which id was generated for the new user, so that I can use it when inserting the new role.

Is this possible? If it is, how should it be done?

Want to do something like following:

```
<insert tableName="xxx_user">
    <!-- Id is auto incremented -->
    <column name="user_name" value="XXX" />
    <column name="password" value="XXX" />
    <column name="first_name" value="XXX" />
    <column name="last_name" value="XXX" />
</insert>

<insert tableName="user_role">
    <column name="user_id" value="<point at the auto generated id in previous insert>" />
    <column name="role" value="A_ROLE" />
</insert>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql function for last inserted id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id)

Comment: Please show us your Liquibase change set, but you most probably are looking for `lastval()` or `currval()` - or you can do it with just a single data modifying CTE.

Comment: This can be easily done with pure vendor specific SQL. But I try to do it in Liquibase where it is done by using XML and is not specific to any vendor.

Comment: Have added an Liquibase example of what I want to do

Comment: You could try `valueComputed="lastval()"` but that would be vendor specific again. I don't think Liquibase has any support for this kind of things. Unrelated, but: do you _really_ have table named `user` - that is a bad idea because `user` is a reserved word and [requires to be quoted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) each time you use it.

Comment: Thx, will try it out. The table and column names are actually different in my code :)

Answer (score 12):

I use Mysql DB. It is not an elegant solution but works...

```
    <column name="user_id" valueComputed="(SELECT MAX(id) FROM xxx_user)"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think the downvotes are undeserved here. This is the only successful method of retrieving an ID that I have found so far. As the author noted, it is not an elegant solution but it does bridge the gap of finding the auto-generated ID.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column `xxx_user.user_name` is unique:

```
<column name="user_id" valueComputed="(SELECT id FROM xxx_user WHERE user_name = 'XXX')"/>
```

Using `MAX(id)` is a bit risky: Theoretically, something besides your Liquibase script could add another `xxx_user` entry just between your first and your second insert, causing your second insert to reference the wrong `xxx_user`.