# How to get last insert id for FOREIGN TABLE?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

When inserting row into PosgreSQL **FOREIGN TABLE** I can not use CURRVAL/LASTVAL because these functions should get value from Postgre sequence, but here row is inserted into MySQL backend and the AUTOINCREMENT is changed.

Is there any way to get LASTINSERTID for that field?
(mysql_fdw postgresql extention officially do not support [this](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw/issues/95))

**UPD**
I have one suggestion to the topic.
To solve this problem it seems the mysql_fdw extention should implement some UDF so I could `SELECT MYSQL_FDW_LASTINSERT_ID` which in turn will issue `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to MySQL backend for *current session*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id

Comment: SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: @Jordan: this is not safe. What return value will be if concurent transaction will insert and commit new row?

Comment: @lolka_bolka: I can not use `CURRVAL/LASTVAL because these functions should get value from Postgre sequence, but here row is inserted into MySQL backend`. Have you notice that?