# How do I properly insert data into both tables, with one of them having a foreign key to the other table?

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

Currently, I've got these 2 tables in my database:

Users

```
id - Primary Key
fname
lname
email
password
level
```

Authorizations

```
id_network
id_user - FK to id on table Users
network
```

The PHP code that I was thinking of doing was something like this. And I am aware that this code is vulnerable to SQL injections, I will fix it, but I haven't done so yet.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (id, pnome, unome, email, pass, level) VALUES (DEFAULT, '$pnome', '$unome', '$email', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)";
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);

$query = "INSERT INTO authorizations (id_network, id_user, network) VALUES ('$id', ?????, 'Facebook')";
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
```

My question is, what do I put in place of the question marks of the Authorization table insertion? 
Since there is the `id_user` foreign key to the Users table, and I wish to use the `id` from the entry that I just inserted into Users, how do I make sure that I am using that specific entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgreSQL, there's no concept of last insert ID. You can use either `curval()` or `lastval()`. You can also use a query that returns the `id`:

```sql
INSERT INTO `users` (
    `fname`, `lname`, `email` -- ...
) VALUES (
    'Smith', 'John', -- ...
) RETURNING `id`;
```

More info: [postgreSQL function for last inserted ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/)