# How do I get the “id” after INSERT into a postgres database with Python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am doing an INSERT into a postgres DB, which has an auto increment field called id.

How do I get the value of id after doing the insert in Python?  There are good references on this site to this for MySQL databases (i.e. using cursor.lastrowid, or connection.insert_id()) but these don't seem to work with my postgres DB.

The id field is using a sequence to auto increment. So the id field is not null, default, nextval('table_id_seq')

Thanks

Comment: Please also mention the library you are to make connection with postgres. Is it PyODBC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgreSQL function for last inserted ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id)

Answer (score 4):

Pls try that:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO .... RETURNING
id_of_new_row = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: It should be `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO .... RETURNING primary_key_field_name;`