# postgres return last id codeigniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm new with postgres database codeigniter

for return last id in mysql 
im using this in my model

```
public function daftar($data){
                $this->db->insert('akun', $data);
                return $this->db->insert_id();
            }
```

but I'm confuse how to return las id ($this->db->insert_id) in postgres?

Comment: I think simple $this->db->insert_id(); will work

Comment: what is this `$akun_id_akun_seq` ???

Comment: name  sequence for coloumn id_akun in table akun
I forget to delete it

Comment: replace this `return $this->db->insert_id();` and add `echo $this->db->insert_id(); die;`

Answer (score 4):

From the [CodeIgniter documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html#information-from-executing-a-query):

> If using the PDO driver with PostgreSQL, or using the Interbase driver, this function requires a $name parameter, which specifies the appropriate sequence to check for the insert id.

In your case you need `return $this->db->insert_id('akun_id_akun_seq');` if "akun_id_akun_seq" is the name of the respective sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If your INSERT is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO public."MyTable"
(
    "SomethingIdFk", 
    "Date"
) 
VALUES 
(
    8, 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And MyTable has a serial like `MyTableId` as primary key, then in your model you can do this:

```
$id= $this->db->insert_id('public."MyTable_MyTableId_seq"');
```

to get the last insert id.

That works for me.

More info you can find in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id).