# Postgresql INSERT - auto get next id?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and the database tool. I had an issue with some data, so I deleted a row but then wanted to add a couple more...

I used the clone option:

[image]

I then modified my values and hit the `commit` button.

However, the insert failed with the error:

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Primary Key some_table" Detail: Key (id)=(58) already exists.

I then tried via the console and inserting manually, but I get the same error.
Each time I do this, the id increments... I have thousands of records, so I cannot keep clicking until my finger snaps off.

This is what `id` looks like (when table is created):

```
id bigserial not null constraint "Primary Key some_table"
primary key
```

When I try to modify the table, I see id has a default value set as this:

```
nextval('some_table_id_seq'::regclass)
```

I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id,...columns..) VALUES (DEFAULT,...columns...);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO some_table (...columns..) VALUES (...columns...);
```

but I get the same error...

I realise I could do something [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id) running a query to get the MAX `id` and *then* do my insert, but that seems a little ridiculous to me.

How can tailor my `INSERT` so that it automatically gets the new/next `id`?

For example, MSSQL has automatically handles this for you using `newid()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what the problem was...

I had **previously cloned the table**, which then also cloned the sequence. This is what was causing the problem: the default value in the `id` column of `some_table` was using the sequence from the OLD, cloned table...

I modified the sequence name to use a new sequence, and it worked.

Also, when doing an insert, you can replace use:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id,...columns..) VALUES (nextval('some_table_id_seq'::regclass),...columns...);
```

to automatically generate the `id` (same as referencing `DEFAULT`)

Thank you everyone for your help. Lesson learned: do not clone tables; don't be lazy.

Answer (score 7):

If you sequence gets out of sync with the underlying data (due to manually entered records, or ids that came from the wrong sequence), you can reset them with a command such as:

```
SELECT SETVAL('some_table_id_seq',MAX(id)+1) FROM some_table
```

This just finds the highest ID in the table currently and then updates the sequence to the next available value.

Docs:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either skip the column in column list on insert, or use DEFAULT keyword, like here:

```
t=# create table i (i bigserial, t text);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 99.579 ms
t=# insert into i (t) select null;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 75.390 ms
t=# insert into i values(DEFAULT,null);
INSERT 0 1
Time: 58.365 ms
t=# select * from i;
 i | t
---+---
 1 |
 2 |
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I've updated my post - I've tried both of those methods and unfortunately, neither work.

Comment: It actually looks like he is in fact using sequence (considering he gets incremented value in each error message), but it lags behind of what is already inserted in database, because likely something inserted values with manually specified PK and that left sequence unused.

Comment: @pookie If your sequence is behind the actual values, you can of course easily reset it - but first identify who is inserting values overheading the sequence

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Yes, it seems there is a sequence. Please see updated question.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński thanks for your notice! I was answering OP's questions, loosing the actual problem

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Just me using the DB. Records inserted via 1 virtual machine and I am trying to now insert a record manually on another virtual machine. I've not touched the id's - no idea what resetting the sequence means, what it entails or what the implications will be.

Comment: @pookie please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to reset it to what you want if you know what it should be and that is what follows:  "alter sequence schema.table_id_seq restart with xx"  (where xx is the next available number).  This works with 12.x and 13.x and schema is the name of your schema and table is the name of your table!

Answer (score -2):

You can try this,

```
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Employee_Activity")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
       val_id=(row[0])
    val_id+=1
```

**val_id can be fetched and incremented automatically**