# QT QPSQL table insert return column

Tags: postgresql, qt, insert, return-value

Using Qt Creator 4.1.0 based on Qt 5.6.

I have a postgresql table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE shelf (
 bookid sequence,
 title character varying(200),
 author character varying(200),
 publisher character varying(200),
 isbn character varying(200),
 genre character varying(200)
);
```

I have just done a successful insert

```
QSqlQuery que;
que.exec("insert into shelf(title) values('blah') returning bookid;");
```

The insert worked fine,  how to I get returning bookid?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 while (que.next()) {
        QString bookid = que.value(0).toString();
         qDebug() << bookid;
    }
```

?..

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to get the last insert id when using Qt and PostgreSQL:

1. **Using [`lastInsertId()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId):** This has the advantage of being **portable** (i.e. your code keeps working if you decide to change to another DBMS later on), but it **[might be unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944481/2666212)** if you had triggers in your database that fire upon insertion in your table (e.g. `shelf`) and insert other values in other tables (note that it is [implemented](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp?h=5.10#n532) by issuing the query `SELECT lastval();` on PostgreSQL). When using this approach, your code should look something like this:

   ```
   QSqlQuery query;
   query.prepare("INSERT INTO some_table(col_name) VALUES(?);");
   query.addBindValue("sth");
   if(!query.exec()) //insert statement failed
       qWarning() << "insert statement failed with error: "
                  << query.lastError().databaseText();
   int insertId = query.lastInsertId().toInt();
   //do anything you want with the id
   qDebug() << "id: " << insertId;
   ```
2. **Using the `RETURNING` clause:** This has the advantage of being **safer** in case you had the weird triggers mentioned above, but it is **not portable** (i.e. the insert statement won't execute if you ever decide to change to another DBMS because it is not standard SQL anymore). This way, your code should look something like this:

   ```
   QSqlQuery query;
   query.prepare("INSERT INTO some_table(col_name) VALUES(?) RETURNING id_col_name;");
   query.addBindValue("sth");
   if(!query.exec()) //insert statement failed
       qWarning() << "insert statement failed with error: "
                  << query.lastError().databaseText();
   if(!query.next()) //returning clause failed
       qWarning() << "returning clause did not return any data";
   int insertId = query.value(0).toInt();
   //do anything you want with the id
   qDebug() << "id: " << insertId;
   ```

Comment: I tried the first, it worked fine.  I don't understand the  bind value, I looked it up but didn't make any sense to me.  At the moment I have not triggers.  Is it legal to post links ? here goes....  My complete example is on github at https://github.com/vince-br-549/PubStor

Comment: Seems to work both with and without the  addBindValue("sth");  I don't understand, the doc for it, didn't help me :)

Comment: @Vince `prepare()`/`addBindValue()` are about using [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) which are mostly utilized to mitigate [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your code certainly works both ways, but you should always prefer to write safe code...

Comment: Thanks Mike,  I had seen use of prepare stmts before but diidn't realize how they would work to prevent injection attacks,  The light came on here :)