# How get id after inserting a new row of data into the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have:

```
Insert Into(name)
Value('Anton')
```

How do I get the newly created `id`?

Comment: Which dialect of SQL are you using?  MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc?  They all have different approaches.

Comment: I added now,sorry.

Comment: Did you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Insert a single row into table distributors, returning the sequence
>   number generated by the DEFAULT clause:

**Code**

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets')
   RETURNING did;
```

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return
>   value(s) based on each row actually inserted. This is primarily useful
>   for obtaining values that were supplied by defaults, such as a serial
>   sequence number. However, any expression using the table's columns is
>   allowed. The syntax of the RETURNING list is identical to that of the
>   output list of SELECT.

**Reference**:

1. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-insert.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944481/7793817

Answer (score 0):

You use the RETURNING keyword

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/dml-returning.html

From the doc :

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Joe', 'Cool') RETURNING id;
```