# Dapper issue with postgres returning id or select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('<table>','<id>'))?

Tags: postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I'm trying to use Dapper, Npgsql to connect to a postgres database from a .net application. After an insert, I want to know the id of inserted row. I have read and tried options [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id).
I have tried using `returning id` like so:

```
id = connection.Execute("insert into document_tag (tag) values (@tag) returning id;",
            new { tag },
            transaction);
```

but I get only '1' in id.

I also tried to use `currval` like so:

```
id = connection.Execute("insert into document_tag (tag) values (@tag); select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('document_tag','id'));",
            new { tag },
            transaction);
```

Even in this case, I get only '1' in `id`.

In both cases, the insert was successful and the *id* column in the database had a valid serial number other than '1'.

Is my expectation wrong or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert a row and get back a database-generated column, use:

```
INSERT INTO document_tag (tag) VALUES (@tag) RETURNING id
```

Note that there is no semicolon before "RETURNING" - it's just a clause of the INSERT statement, [as you can see in the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

In addition, once you add a RETURNING clause, the INSERT statement returns a resultset containing the requested information, just as if you executed a SELECT statement. Dapper's `Execute()` is meant to execution without resultsets, so you will need to switch to `Query()`, and probably add a `Single()` method to extract the single value you need. An alternative would be `ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: Thanks @Shay. I'm sorry it was a typo. I edited the line before posting.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Shay: using `connection.QueryFirst<int>` instead of `connection.Exeucte` and got it working. Updated working code:

```
id = connection.QueryFirst<int>("insert into document_tag (tag) values (@tag) returning id;",
        new { tag },
        transaction);
```