# Inserting primary and child records

Tags: postgresql, insert, repository, loopback4

Following the insert of a record into a postgresql table with a generated primary key, how can I get that key so that I can insert child table records and specify their foreign key? Does the first insert return the primary key in the inserted model object? Or must I query for the inserted record using some findOne criteria? Or, lastly, is this all handled by the hasMany and belongsTo mechanism?

Comment: Does this discussion answer your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id

Answer (score 0):

> Does the first insert return the primary key in the inserted model object

Yes. The repository function `.create()` will return an instance of the Model with the ID. However note that the other functions (such as `replaceById()`) don't return the Model instance (they return `void` instead).

A new "child" model instance can then be created with the foreign key referencing the aforementioned ID.