# insert a batch into multiple tables and use the id generated in the first

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two tables and a array of values to insert:
table1 (id, name, createdAt, updatedAt)
table2(id, name, table1Id)

Is there any way in postgresql or sequelize to make a bulkCreate, adding records in both tables and using the id generated in the insert of table1 as foreign key of the second table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id

Comment: You are missing significant necessary information. Take a few minuets to review [ask]. Specifically, update your question to include table definitions (ddl) and sample data (or even better a fiddle) and the expected results of that data. All as text - no images.

Comment: You can use the `returning` command after the `insert` command. Example: `insert into table1 (name1, name2) values (pname1, pname2) returning id into p_id`